# Difference between WorkBooks.Open and Open

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

can someone explain me what is the difference between this two commands in VBA:

```
WorkBooks.Open "Book.xlsx"
```

```
Open "Book.xlsx" For Random As 1#
```

By the way the second code gives me the following error: Run-time error '55' File already open

However, the error is strange because when I use the first code no already opened file is detected.

Any hints is appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: `Open` by itself is for reading things like text files. Keep in mind that when using either, you will want to include a full path, not just the filename.

Comment: [`Workbooks.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) vs [`Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement).